# Disable or Lock JSF SelectOneListBox

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to disable a JSF SelectOneListBox so that user can only see, but can not change the selection. When I used disabled = "true" ,the selection cannot be read by the user as the font colour and the selection colour becomes gray. I used readonly="true", still the users can change the selection. What is the way to allow the user to see the selection clearly, but do not allow to change the selection?

Comment: I could make it read by changing the disabledClass in CSS, but in the application I have allowed user to change themes by PrimeFaces,so that this style will remain the same if I do it despite theme change.

Comment: If you must show the `<h:selectOneListBox>` when the user should only read data, why not using another component like datatable or `<ui:repeat>` to just show the values, and you can use the "rendered" attribute in the component to know when one of them must be shown.

Comment: On the left side of the web page, all the items are listed. On the right side,the details of the selected items are displayed. Until the user click the edit button, the details displayed on the right side can not be changed. So I can not use <ui:repeat> in my case. Please have a look on local server example http://124.43.26.62:8080/ho/faces/tem_institutions.xhtml

Comment: Are you using JSF `<h:selectOneListbox>` or PrimeFaces `<p:selectOneListbox>`? Your question does nowhere explicitly mention PrimeFaces, only your comment. This detail is too important to be omitted from the question. PrimeFaces is not part of standard JSF, it's a JSF component library.

Comment: I use primefaces to get the themes, but use <h:selectOneListbox> as the Listbox.